# System.js: right way to load registered modules

Tags: angular, systemjs

After digging in questions here I could'nt find answer to my simple one: I want to register module via system js, then to import it, and cant make it work.

here my index.html, I guess I miss something very basic

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <base href="/" />
  <script data-require="zone.js@0.4.1" data-semver="0.4.1" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/zone.js/v0.4.1/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.14/system.src.js"></script>
  <script>

    System.config({
      baseURL: "/",
      //defaultJSExtensions: 'js',
      transpiler: 'babel',
      packages: {
        'app': {
          format: 'system',
          defaultExtension: false 
        }
      }
    });

       System.register('app/bootstrap', function() {
      return {
        execute: function() {
          document.getElementById('example').textContent = 'execute';
          console.log('execute');
        }
      }
    });
    System.import('app/bootstrap').then(function() {
      console.log(a, 'loaded');
    }, function(a) {
      document.getElementById('example').textContent = 'problem'; 
      console.log(a, 'problem');

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="example"></div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### SystemJS 2.0

Droped the register('name',[],function) name parameter
Now it is only register([],function) and you need a extra to register and import named register calls.

### SystemJS > 6.x

You need to add the code from the extra that supports that

https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/HEAD/dist/extras/named-register.js

but you can also call it directly after it has registered even without name support

```js
System.register([], function () {
    'use strict';
    return {
        execute: function () {

            console.log('breave heart !!!!!!!!!!!');

        }
    };
});
System.getRegister()[1]({},System).execute()
```

getRegister gets the last registered module as array the first entry is a array of dependencies and secund is the execute function that takes exports and module parameters this are a extra chapter it should be fine to use a empty object and then System

if this needs even more explaination please leave a comment.